# Git pushes to wrong gerrit change

Tags: git, gerrit

I tried to push to gerrit after my new commit but I get this error:
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change (here is my change link) closed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'link to my repo'

The change link is the change I made before on this repo, but has completely different change ID then my current commit, I tried switching branches, rebasing, pulling changes etc. Everything is up to date but if I push it only wants to push to my last closed commit instead of creating a new change in gerrit

Did someone had a similar problem? I only noticed a post where someone had the same ID on his new commit but I have different change ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue and resolved it.

I don't really understand how it works, but my last commit I had (on completely different branch) for some reason stayed after being pushed? Meaning that it still had some changes to be pushed even though it had none. And when I was finished working on my other branch with my other commit, when trying to push to gerrit, git wanted to push both of those commits, even though the last one shouldn't be pushed at all because it had no changes to push and was on a different branch... Perhaps some bug from gerrit.

But anyway, I used `git rebase -i` and just deleted the line with the buggy commit
Everything works correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

When you push a commit with a fresh new ChangeID, unique in the target branch, which you can find in the commit message, Gerrit creates a Pending Change for the commit. The commit is the first patch set of the Pending Change.

Before the patch set is approved and submitted, you can amend it, including `git commit --amend`, `git rebase`, `git cherry-pick`, rebase on the page. These actions do not change the ChangeID in the commit message. After you push the new commit, Gerrit knows that it's a new patch set of an existing Pending Change instead of a new Pending Change because the target branch is the same and the ChangeID is the same.

In your case, the error indicates one of the pushed new commits has the same ChangeID with the commit of your change link. It tries to update the Pending Change with a new patch set. However, the Change is read-only, Merged or Abandoned, which leads to push rejection.

If the Pending Change is abandoned and you want to update it with the new patch set, you can restore it before a new push and you will get a new patch set of the Pending Change.

If you don't want to update it with the new patch set, or if the Change is already merged, you can amend the commit that has the same ChangeID. Remove the ChangeID line and let the commit-msg hook generate a fresh new ChangeID. Push the amended commit and you will get a new Pending Change.

If the commit happens to be the last commit, `git commit --amend` and removing the ChangeID is enough. If it is not the last commit, use `git rebase -i O --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit'`. The `O` is the parent of your oldest commit among the new commits to be pushed. In the rebase todo, modify the word before the target commit to `r` or `reword`. After the rebase process starts, it will let you to modify its commit message. Remove the ChangeID line then. `git commit --amend --no-edit` makes sure `commit-msg` is invoked and a new ChangeID is generated.

If there are more than one such commit, repeat the process until all new commits have new ChangeIDs or their associated Changes are writable.